# Sentiment analysis using bigrams

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

So I have some reviews that I am trying to classify into positive or negative. I am trying to use NLTK and Stanford coreNLP to do so. I am able to do it on unigrams but its not working for bigrams. I tried the following for bigrams

```
def classifySentence(sen):
  wn_lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
  pos = 0
  neg = 0
  stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
  filtered_review = [token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(sen) if not token in stop_words]


  for token in nltk.bigrams(filtered_review):
      #lemma = wn_lem.lemmatize(token)
      # print("lemma="+token)
      if len(wn.synsets(token))>0:
          synset = wn.synsets(token)[0]
          #print("synset.name="+synset.name())

          sent = swn.senti_synset(synset.name())

          #print("Sentiment of "+token+" "+str(sent))

          pos = pos + sent.pos_score()
          neg = neg + sent.neg_score()
          # print (token + "(pos_score): " + str(pos) +"\n")
          # print (token + "(neg_score): " + str(neg) +"\n")
  #print (filtered_review)
  JoinedTokens = ' '.join(wo for wo in filtered_review)
  return [JoinedTokens, pos, neg]
```

I was wondering if someone could suggest me ways to do this. I would like to use NLTK or can also use stanfordcoreNLP. I am also open to using other python packages but just need some guidance
I have written some code for using it but it didn't work either. The code I wrote

```
def StanfordBigrams():
  nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
  operations = {'annotators': 'tokenize,lemma,pos,sentiment', 'outputFormat': 'json'}
  string = "not bad"
  tok = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
  bigrams = nltk.bigrams(tok)
  res = nlp.annotate(str(bigrams),operations)
  for s in res["sentences"]: 
          for token in s["tokens"]:
              print("Sentiment: "+str(s["sentiment"])+"SentimentValue: "+str(s["sentimentValue"]))
              print (token)
```

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Post your errors and stack traces for when it's 'not working'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you training a sentiment classifier, or just trying to use one? Technically, I suspect your error is in `wn.synset(bigram)` -- I doubt the thing returned from `nltk.bigrams` is a word that can be passed into WordNet.

But, more importantly, you probably want to pass your whole sentence into a sentiment classifier -- bigrams aren't going to have sentiments annotated on them in things like SentiWordNet, and the trained sentiment classifiers are going to have a much easier time on sentences than they are on short snippets. You should be able to get sentiment for *some* of the bigrams in the sentence from Stanford's sentiment tree (vs just the sentiment value at the root). See the `sentimentTree` field on the JSON output from the CoreNLP server.